# GitHub pages return 404 error when directly accessing to sub link

Tags: github, travis-ci, github-pages

When I go to https://paisoemoe.github.io/shopping it work just fine but if i go straight to sublinks like https://paisoemoe.github.io/shopping/products/women/all or https://paisoemoe.github.io/shopping/products/shoes/all, then it return 404 error even though the pages are there. Why is this happening and how can i fix that? I deployed with travis Ci.